# Wire connectors for Back of Push to Exit Button

Tags: terminal, crimp

The connection terminals on the back of these Request to Exit buttons seem to resemble what I can guess is a "compression lugs".  Not really sure what they are called and I'm not familiar with general strategy to connect wires to these types of terminals.

Without knowing the precise size, what is the type of connector one would crimp to end of a wire to securely connect to these type of lugs?

Product:
https://www.visionistech.com/en/product/exit-button-vis-7000/

[image: Switch]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Mouser sells over 186000 switches It is very unlikely that anybody around here has ever used exactly that switch for any project before. So how should others here deal with your question? They only could ask the manufacturer about the size of the contact flanges. But this is something which can be done by you as well.

Comment: Knowing they are called "flanges" helps actually.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look to me like "Faston(tm)" connectors (also called "spade" or "quick connect").  There are mating female connectors that slide over the male tabs.  These connectors are avaiable in several widths - most common is 1/4".

Searching for "faston connector" at Digikey or other distributors should find lots of compatible connectors.

Comment: I found this article useful also: https://blog.delcity.net/how-to-wire-a-toggle-switch/